# Crear un cron para revisar si una tabla fue actualizada

Tags: php, mysql, cronjobs

soy un poco nuevo con los cron jobs, mi consulta es si hay alguna manera de revisar cada x minutos/horas si una tabla en una base de datos fue actualizada y obtener información de esos nuevos registros y cómo se podría implementar.

***EDIT***

Estoy trabajando en un sitio (bastante mal hecho btw) y lo que necesitan es que una vez que ellos cargan ciertos clientes a una base (manualmente mediante sentencias SQL) se les mande un mail a estos clientes notificándoles que ya han sido confirmados por email junto a un archivo.

Comment: ¿Qué tan nuevo es «un poco nuevo»?

Comment: hace un par de años he creado unos cronjobs, pero muy sencillos.

Comment: Tienes que considerar varias cosas, por ejemplo lo que necesitas hacer con la informacion, es decir, necesitas automatizar un proceso que revise la actividad de una tabla eso esta muy bien, la pregunta es que necesitas hacer con esa informacion y como la vas a consumir, depende de esa respuesta podrias automatizar ese proceso con un cronjob, un procedimiento almacenado en la misma bd, tambien con un script Phyton. Explicanos mejor lo que necesitas hacer para poder orientarte.

Comment: Como tal, un cron suele hacerse con un script que realiza la tarea básica, y luego con un programador (en Linux se suele usar cron) se le dice que ejecute el script cada ciertas horas. Otra forma sería que utilizaras reactphp, haciendo que el propio script tenga un timer  cada hora. Revisa lo que más te interese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentare orientarte considerando la mayor cantidad de posibilidades para la implementacion de la solucion a tu requerimiento,es una implementacion amplia de la cual no contamos con todo el detalle, sin embargo, hago todo el esfuerzo de hacerte ver la solucion.

Primero que nada estaría muy preocupado por poner la carga de enviar correos electrónicos en el servidor de base de datos (por pequeño que sea) considerando el mal diseño de la aplicacion como tu mismo lo has dicho.

Podría sugerir una de estas alternativas:

- Haz que la lógica de la aplicación detecte la necesidad de enviar un
  correo electrónico y enviarlo.
- Haz que un trigger MySQL llene una tabla que ponga en cola los
  correos electrónicos que se enviarán y haga que un proceso monitoree
  esa tabla y envíe los correos electrónicos.

Te adjunto varios enlaces con soluciones que se podrian amoldar a tus necesidades:

- Implementacion de envio de correos con PHP:
  [Enlace](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/2036.php)
- Enviar correo con Python:
  [Enlace](https://ricardogeek.com/como-enviar-emails-con-python/)
- Conectarte a la base de datos y ejecutar consultas con Python:
  [Enlace](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-12/conectarse-a-la-base-de-datos-y-ejecutar-consultas)
- Envio de correo de Python con SMTP:
  [Enlace](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/sending-emails-in-python-with-smtp--cms-29975)

**Ejemplo de conexion y consulta a la BD**

```
 import MySQLdb
 db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user",passwd="contra",db="basedatos")
 c = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
 c.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
 result_set = c.fetchall()
 for row in result_set:
 print(row["Nombre"])
```

**Ejemplo de envio de correo en Python con SMTP**

```
# import necessary packages

 from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
 from email.mime.text import MIMEText
 import smtplib

 # create message object instance
 msg = MIMEMultipart()


message = "Thank you"

# setup the parameters of the message
password = "your_password"
msg['From'] = "your_address"
msg['To'] = "to_address"
msg['Subject'] = "Subscription"

# add in the message body
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

#create server
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')

server.starttls()

# Login Credentials for sending the mail
server.login(msg['From'], password)


# send the message via the server.
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

server.quit()

print "successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To'])
```

Comment: Se ve excelente. Entonces la 'idea principal' es tener una tabla donde ponga en cola los pendientes a avisar, y cada x tiempo revisarla si es necesario enviarlos ?

Comment: Exactamente ese es el concepto. Saludos!

Comment: Personalmente no estoy de acuerdo con los triggers. Este tipo de problema (enviar un correo) es cosa de lógica de negocio, no de bbdd. Tú aplicación debería hacer el guardado correspondiente y a mayores mandar el email. Esto último puedes hacerlo con mensajería tipo rabbitmq, con un consumers que se encargue de mandar el email. Si lo haces con un trigger estás acoplando tu app al gestor de bbdd